# jQuery Zoom function not working; Chrome posting error

Tags: jquery, zooming, typeerror

I'm trying to use [this code](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) to 'Zoom' on [this page](http://yosemitefallscafe.net/menu.html). Unfortunately, I'm receiving an error from Chrome, which would explain why it's not working. Chrome's posting this:
    
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#ex1').zoom();
            });

"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).zoom is not a function"
highlighting this specifically > `$('#ex1').zoom();`

My problem is why Chrome is posting this error, when the code I'm using is EXACTLY how the demo is using it.

Am I experiencing a script conflict somewhere?

Comment: Okay, I've managed to get rid of the error using:

<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {
   $("#ex1").zoom();
  })(jQuery);
 </script>

but the function still isn't working. I have no 'zoom' functioning at all.

Any clues?

Comment: Make sure you are not loading js file in `<link `. I made that mistake once.

Comment: This plugin doesn't currently work with jQuery version 2.x.x. I switched to jQuery version 1.10.2 and it works straight away.